# ajaxStart ignores .show() in Google Chrome

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome

I have a jQuery $.ajax call which works fine in all major browsers.

Additionally I make use of .ajaxStart and .ajaxStop functions to make 
an invisible div on my page that says "loading..." , visible.

The problem is that while both ,ajaxStart and .ajaxStop , events fire
without any problems (I check it from the console.log()) , the .show event
of jQuery in ajaxStart is completelly ignored in Google Chrome.

Here is the code :

```
$("#loadMsg").ajaxStart(function(){
   console.log('ajaxstart');
   // the next command is ignored ONLY in Google Chrome
   $(this).show(0);
}); 

$.ajax({
  url:"xxx.php",
  type:"POST",
  data:"id="+id,
  async:false,
  success:function(data)
  {
     console.log(data); 
  }
});  

$("#loadMsg").ajaxStop(function(){
  console.log('ajaxfinish');
  $(this).hide(0);
});
```

I already tried:

```
$("#loadMsg").show(0);  
$("#loadMsg").fadeIn();  
$("#loadMsg").css("display","block");  
$("#loadMsg").css("display","inline");
```

etc.

Any suggestions would be really appreciated.

Comment: It's seems that this code is working http://jsfiddle.net/dBSD7/. I've deleted async:false, because don't know why you want to be that. :) Also, +1 for your nickname :)

Comment: I know this is working if async:true , but...I'm expecting some data from the ajax request before proceeding with the rest of the code.I didn't expose the whole code in success parameter (sorry for that)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 2 days of struggling I finally found the solution.
The whole code I posted above was inside a function,which returned the result of xxx.php via the success property to the main code.

The problem was that when I used the **async:true** option ,the function returned immediately the return value without waiting for ajax to complete the request.
So the returned value had always a value of "undefined" and not the proper outcome of xxx.php.

The solution of **running ajax asynchronous and proceeding with the rest of the code ONLY when the ajax request is completed** , is to place the whole code inside success parameter.

I'll try to make it clear with the following example:

**Code that didn't work :**

```
function foo()
{

 if call_ajax_request()=="true"
  {
    //execute code A
    // never had the chance to be executed because call_ajax_request() 
    // was always undefined
  }

}



function call_ajax_request()
{

  var return_value;

  $.ajax({
  url:"xxx.php",
  type:"POST",
  data:"z="+y,
  success:function(data)
    {
           return_value = data;
        }
    }); 

    //return_value was always "undefined" because the flow didn't wait
   // for ajax to complete (async mode)
   return return_value;
}
```

**code that finally did the job :**

```
function foo()
{

  $.ajax({
   url:"xxx.php",
   type:"POST",
   data:"z="+y,
   success:function(data)
     {
            return_value = data;

            //here, the following code won't be executed 
            //as long as ajax hasn't been completed.

            if (return_value=="true")
            {
               //execute code A
            }
         }
   }); 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with async:false, which will cause the browser to hang until the request completes. Instead of trying to use async:false, I urge you to consider reworking your project so that it works asynchronously.

Comment: But it works on all other browsers.Only Google's Chrome has this behavior.Thanks anyway for the reply and your suggestion.

Comment: The matter is that I'm expecting a "true" or "false" value from the ajax request I send to xxx.php.
If I omit the async:false property...the execution doesn't wait for the php result (which is critical for the rest of the programm) and continues with execution AS IF xxx.php had send "false" as a return value.
How can I force the ajax request to wait for execution if async=true ?